# image takes up whole table cell width and height in CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I make an `image` takes up whole `table cell` width and height even if image size is smaller than table cell? My image is inside `div` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following CSS - example here -> http://jsfiddle.net/Pq67x/1/

```
<style>
    div {
        width:50px;
        height:100px;
    }

    div img {
        height:100%;
        width: 100%;
        max-width:100%;
        max-height:100%;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <img src='path/to/img.gif' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/chricholson/8Xer3/. It will distort the image though: http://jsfiddle.net/chricholson/8Xer3/1/. You also don't need the div by default unless you are doing some other stuff with it: http://jsfiddle.net/chricholson/8Xer3/2/.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>

            <img src="http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2001-24-a-web.jpg" />

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td {
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    background: yellow;
}

img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```